# How do we show timezone in different format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to show **timezone** in a different format. I have a variable that gets the timezone of the user called as `timeZone` returning value of timezone as `Asia/Calcutta`.

```
console.log(timeZone) // "Asia/Calcutta"
```

But is it possible to show timezone in different format like **PDT** or **UTC** or **IST** with `moment.js`?

> Timeformat: `2019-01-28 24:59:59` **UTC**

Comment: Please add an example time (including timezone).

Comment: I have updated the question with time format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timezones depending on locations are not something that can be calculated. You need a database which handles this for you.

`moment-timezone` is one of the most famous.

If you install `moment-timezone` you can do

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Among other options, as stated here: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Why do I require to add jun? Can't I just change that timezone to other formats without having to put date?

Comment: @Santosh `jun` is just a `moment` date. You can see how it works and all the documentation in the link I passed you. PD: Edited my answer.